# how do I pass null to int column in linq

Tags: linq, int, nullable

How do we assign null value to int column in LINQ.
eg.

```
 SQLDBDataContext sqlD = new SQLDBDataContext();
 var result = from p in sqlD.loadsRadius(Convert.ToInt32(Request["radius"]), .....
```

here if Request["radius"] is null gives an error.

I could pass 0 via this but I need to change in many already existing procedures.

Thanks in advance.
[Anil](http://www.ade-technologies.com)

Answer (score 4):

You need to case the int to a null, eg:

```
var result = from p in sqlD.loadsRadius(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["radius"]) ? (int?)null : int.Parse(Request["radius"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the exception is a FormatException, my guess is that the value returned by Request["radius"] is actually the string "null". If Request["radius"] actually returned null, Convert.ToInt32() would return zero.  You may try using using int.TryParse() to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Codechef..

```
int radius = -1;
int.TryParse(Request["radius"],out radius)
if(radius > 0) // you can remove this clause if you don't want this
{
SQLDBDataContext sqlD = new SQLDBDataContext();
 var result = from p in sqlD.loadsRadius(radius)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into nullable types: [Here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Request["radius"] ?? "0")
```

If Request["radius"] equals to null, it will return "0" instead.